# PostgreSQL and hibernate query.uniqueResult error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, postgresql

I have to change a system that works with oracle database to PostgreSQL. 
The below query, when run in the PostgreSQL query builder, returns '8',

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  from database.client c  
  left join database.salutation t  on c.SALUTATIONID = t.SALUTATIONID  
  left join database.add_details ad  on ad.ADDDETAILID = c.ADTYPEID  
  left join database.add_type at  on at.ADDTYPEID = ad.ADDTYPEID  
  left join database.geo_cat g  on g.GEOID = ad.POSCODEID
  left join database.cltype clt  on clt.CLTYPE = '<CLIENTTYPE>'  
  inner join database.mapclient mc
     on mc.CLIENTID = c.CLIENTID 
    and mc.CLTYPEID = clt.CLTYPEID 
    and mc.EFFDATE <= '06-JUN-2014'
```

In the java class, the query is executed as below

```
Query queryCount = getSession().createSQLQuery(countSql);
int count = ((Number) queryCount.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

This works fine with Oracle, but with Postgre, it gives the following error,

> query did not return a unique result: 8

Why does this happen and what can I do for this?

Comment: you could run a list() query and examine the result to gather more information what is going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the select clause to:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) from database.client c
```